# Postgres: "vacuum" command does not clean up dead tuples

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

We have a postgres database in Amazon RDS. Initially, we needed to load large amount of data quickly, so `autovacuum` was turned off according to the [best practice suggestion from Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.PostgreSQL). Recently I noticed some performance issue when running queries. Then I realized it has not been vacuumed for a long time. As it turns out many tables have lots of dead tuples.

[image]

Surprisingly, even after I manually ran `vacuum` commands on some of the tables, it did not seem to remove these dead tuples at all. `vacuum full` takes too long to finish which usually ends up timed out after a whole night.

Why does `vacuum` command not work? What are my other options, restart the instance?

Comment: There's always the brute force option of 1) creating a new table, 2) copying data to it from old table, 3) delete old table, 4) rename new table to old name. Repeated for every table that has a lot of dead rows.

Comment: I think amazon suggests to disable autovacuum for the time of database restore only... In general disable autovacuum only brings problems. it even says in your link: "Important

Not running autovacuum can result in an eventual required outage to perform a much more intrusive vacuum operation... " and so on

Comment: if `vacuum full` times out, set statement_timeout to zero

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `VACUUM (VERBOSE)` to get detailed statistics of what it is doing and why.

There are three reasons why dead tuples cannot be removed:

1. There is a long running transaction that has not been closed.  You can find the bad boys with

   ```
    SELECT pid, datname, usename, state, backend_xmin
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE backend_xmin IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY age(backend_xmin) DESC;
   ```

   You can get rid of a transaction with [`pg_cancel_backend()` or `pg_terminate_backend()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL).
2. There are prepared transactions which have not been commited.  You can find them with

   ```
    SELECT gid, prepared, owner, database, transaction
    FROM pg_prepared_xacts
    ORDER BY age(transaction) DESC;
   ```

   User [`COMMIT PREPARED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commit-prepared.html) or [`ROLLBACK PREPARED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-rollback-prepared.html) to close them.
3. There are [replication slots](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS) which are not used. Find them with

   ```
    SELECT slot_name, slot_type, database, xmin
    FROM pg_replication_slots
    ORDER BY age(xmin) DESC;
   ```

   Use [`pg_drop_replication_slot()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-REPLICATION) to delete an unused replication slot.
4. There is a standby server with `hot_standby_feedback = on` and a long running query.

   Find standby servers that hold back `VACUUM` progress with

   ```
   SELECT application_name, client_addr, backend_xmin
   FROM pg_stat_replication
   ORDER BY age(backend_xmin) DESC;
   ```

Look at [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/) for an in-depth discussion.

Comment: I was able to delete all the dead tuples after killing the transactions. Why do I have so many live tuples though? Do they do anything?

Comment: Yes, they are the data in your tables. After a `VACUUM` the number of rows in a table should be about as many as the number of live tuples.

Comment: All these queries result 0 rows except for 1 which returns only the query itself that pulls this info about pg_stat_activity.

Answer (score 1):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77587/30035 explains why not all dead tuples are removed.

for `vacuum full` not to time out, set `statement_timeout = 0`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.PostgreSQL recommends disabling autovacuum for the time of database restore, further they definetely recommend using it:

> Important
>
> Not running autovacuum can result in an eventual required outage to
>   perform a much more intrusive vacuum operation.

Canceling all sessions and vacuuming table should help with previous dead tuples (regarding your suggestion to restart cluster). But what I suggest you to do in first place - switch autovacuum on. And better probably control vacuum on table, not on the whole cluster with `autovacuum_vacuum_threshold`, (`ALTER TABLE`) reference here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS